# How to solve hot partition problem in consistent hashing Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, system-design, consistent-hashing

I am trying to understand how different Load Balancing strategy works.

One way is to use consistent hashing algorithm where we divide the entire space into multiple virtual nodes and each physical node takes a set of vnodes.

I am not able to understand how would hot partition problem will be solved? It could happen that one particular node is busier than the rest?

Can someone add their experience handling similar use cases? Any pointer to the right document/literature would be helpful.